# How to create a Numpy ufunc over user-defined data types?

Tags: numpy

The [Numpy C API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.ufunc.html#functions) contains a function `PyUFunc_FromFuncAndData` for creating a `PyUFuncObject` data structure.  This function takes a char[] `types` argument that specifies the function's built-in argument types (int, float, etc.).  But, the type number for a user-defined data type is an int, not a char.  If I use the C-API to create a custom (user-defined) data type, how do I create a ufunc that operates on this data type?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this explained in the Numpy documentation, but [there are examples around](http://jayvius.github.io/numpy-dtypes/newufunc.html).

```
int my_type_num = PyArray_RegisterDataType(&my_custom_type_descr);

PyUFuncObject* ufunc = (PyUFuncObject*)PyUFunc_FromFuncAndData(
    NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, nin, nout, identity, name, doc, 0);
PyUFunc_RegisterLoopForType(ufunc, my_type_num, my_loop_func, NULL, NULL);
```

This was discussed relative to an older version of Numpy [on the Numpy mailing list](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-February/031553.html).  The source code for these API functions is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c).